# What type of Keylogger cannot track Skype messages on PC?

Tags: skype, privacy, keylogger

I overheard my IT technicians saying that the company can track all our online messages, communications, activities but not the Skype conversation on our PC/laptop. How is that so?

Isn't the keylogger supposed to be able to "log" everything? in that case, can I assume that whatever is not "published" online, including draft email, is consider "invisible" to the company? (as long as they don't dig my PC)

**UPDATE:**
Maybe they are not using a keylogger, i am not sure and that is what i hope u guys can tell me. All i can be sure is that they blocked our MSN so if we need to use it, we have to use web-base IM like ebuddy which they can log our ebuddy conversation. The reason they did not block skype was because the company use that for work communication with customers and overseas offices.

Comment: Are you sure they didn't mean Skype AUDIO conversations?

Comment: Use the following: Avast Free!; Malware Bytes Anti-Malware; Spybot S&D. Do a boot-time scan with Avast sometimes, and then just use the resident protection. Same goes for Malware Bytes. When you got the time/mood, just run a quick scan. | Avast found all the keyloggers I have encountered so far... so yeah.

Comment: Maybe they are not using a keylogger, i am not sure and that is what i hopr u guys can tell me. All i can be sure is that they blocked our MSN so if we need to use it, we have to use web-base IM like ebuddy which they can log our ebuddy conversation. The reason they did not block skype was because the company use that for work communication with customer and overseas offices.

Comment: Sounds like they're just spinning you a yarn about why you can't have MSN (because it's not needed for company business) but can have Skype (because your company has decided to use it) and they're talking generally about the risks to the business if users are allowed to just install whatever app they like, add plug-ing into those apps etc.   A keylogger will log all keys from all apps.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on many factors.

A keylogger, usually intercept the keystrokes coming from the keyboard and will therefore log everything that is typed. [See Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging)

Most likely they analyze you network traffic(with some basic scripts or something), in which case they can see which domains/online services you use and some of the content which is being transferred.

Some services/websites use encryption to transfer content (ssl) but that only hides what is being sent/received.

EDIT: another interpretation could be that they just archive/monitor all internal communications, like email and instant messages sent though the companies services.